# Spring Integration convert payload to object in service activator

Tags: spring-integration

I am following this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub/) to read email notifications from a topic in Google Pub/Sub. Once the application starts, I see messages arriving on the console like this:

```
Message arrived! Payload: {"emailAddress":"xxxxx@gmail.com","historyId":712315}
```

How do I convert the payload to an object so I can retrieve the emailAddress and historyId?

The service activator looks like this:

```
@Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel")
  public MessageHandler messageReceiver() {
    return message -> {
      LOGGER.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + message.getPayload());
      AckReplyConsumer consumer =
          (AckReplyConsumer) message.getHeaders().get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGEMENT);
      consumer.ack();
    };
  }
```

And the POJO object I want the payload converted to is:

```
public class MessageNotification {

    private String emailAddress;

    private BigInteger historyId;

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public BigInteger getHistoryId() {
        return historyId;
    }

    public void setHistoryId(BigInteger historyId) {
        this.historyId = historyId;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that `payload` is a JSON, so you need to go to Spring Integration [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html) and use a `JsonToObjectTransformer` before handling it with that `@ServiceActivator`:

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel", outputChannel = "handleChannel")
public JsonToObjectTransformer jsonToObjectTransformer() {
    return new JsonToObjectTransformer(MessageNotification.class);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "handleChannel")
public MessageHandler messageReceiver() {

  ...
```

Comment: Lovely jubbly, thanks Artem. I was trying to use the JsonToObjectTransformer within the service activator but I was getting exceptions. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Yeah... That's typical mistake ignoring the fact that Spring Integration expose `MessageChannel` abstraction and allows to build integration flows using channels...

Answer (score -1):

```
You can extract String message first: String jsonString =message.getPayload.toString();

Now you can convert this json string to:

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MessageNotification messageNotification = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString , MessageNotification.class);
```

Comment: Well, this is not Spring Integration way to do things. You really should rely on the Framework as much as possible and get used with the loosely coupling principle and distribution of responsibility not mixing concerns in a single place.